# LEX issues possible yyterminate not sure help!

Tags: c, linux, yacc, lex

hi im having problems with my lex parser. When i use yyterminate to exit as i found an error, it will display the error fine as you can see down the very bottom. But when i go to enter in a new URI it still thinks there is an error in the code. seems like stdin isnt been cleared as it keeps getting the same error. obviously there is code messing, way to much to post in here but this is where i think the problem is with main or yyterminate. any help would be appreciated.

main( int argc, char * argv[] ){

```
char temp[10];
int q; 
while(1)
{
YY_FLUSH_BUFFER;
yyrestart(stdin);
printf("\nPlease enter your URI: ");
        yyin = stdin;

q= yylex();

if(errorFlag !=1)
{
 if(validScheme==1)
 R.protocol = "HTCPCP/1.0";

  R.content = "message/coffee-pot";
  if((helpFlag==1)||(helpFlag==2))
  {
   propfind();
   theServer();
   } 
 }
}
}
 ........
```

here is the main where i should be able to loop around asking for a URI and then go to functions and then return to ask for another uri, this works fine as long as there is no error. 
    ........

```
<sep_state>.       {printf("error in sep state");errorFlag=1; yyterminate(); }
<pot_value>[^0-2]  { printf("Pot Value error"); errorFlag=1; yyterminate(); }
<pot_state>.       { printf("pot state error");errorFlag=1; yyterminate();}
<sep_state>.        { printf("couldnt recognise host");errorFlag=1; yyterminate();}
```

this is where i am doing some error checking. if none of the values have been matched i      want it to error hence it matching all input(i think).
     .......

```
Please enter your URI: coffee://128.0.111.11111/pot-0?

Host not recognised. Use 127.0.0.1/

Please enter your URI: coffee://127.0.0.1/pot-0? 
Host not recognised. Use 127.0.0.1/
```

this is the output to stdout. I want to input a uri parse it send it. when i get an error i want to report the error and start again with a new URI yet, once it gets an error it holds the error even when i type a correct URI in i still get the error. Hope this all makes sense. and would appreciate any help.Cheers

Answer (score 2):

i have managed to overcome the problem, i wasnt resetting the buffer so i j used yyrestart(stdin) this stopped it filling up the screen with the same error, and to get it to recognise a new uri i needed to reset the state, so all is working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can put updates like this in comments to your question or edit the question itself.